# What is the general structure of the complex curve $xy=y^2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

How can you determine how a complex curve looks like in four dimensions, especially near singularities? In my example, the curve $xy=y^2$ consists of the lines $y=x$ and $y=0$ ($x,y$ complex). I think of making a three-dimensional space with points of infinity. Will every line create a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3 \cup {\infty}$ which then is glued together? Or something like that?

Comment: What do you mean by "making a three-dimensional space with points of infinity"?  What does this have to do with your curve?

Comment: Do you mean, what points are in the projective closure of the lines in question. (In this case, these closures are homeomorphic to real $2$-spheres, but note that $\Bbb {CP}^2$ decomposes w.r.t. an affine chart as $\Bbb C^2 \cup \Bbb C^1 \cup \Bbb C^0$, not as $\Bbb R^3 \cup \{\infty\}$, which corresponds to a different *compactification* of $\Bbb C^2$.)

Answer (score 1):

Topologically this affine curve looks like two planes intersecting at a point. If you take its projective closure you'll get two spheres intersecting at a point. I don't understand the rest of your question.